# if ||grad(f(c))|| is not equal to 0 then |D f(c;u) | = || grad(f(c)) ||

Tags: multivariable-calculus

```
 I was trying to answer the **Q.11 from Ch 12 from Mathematical Analysis by Apostol** i.e.
```

let f be real-valued and differentiable at a point c in R^n and assume ||grad(f(c))|| is not equal to 0. Prove that there is one and only one unit vector u in R^n such that |D f(c;u) | = || grad(f(c)) || and that this is the unit vector for which |D f(c;u) | has its maximum value.
   But firstly, I am facing difficulty in convincing myself the problem geometrically. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: When $f$ is differentiable at $c$, you've proved that $Df(c;u) = \text{grad}\,f(c)\cdot u$.

Comment: Yes, using the HINT provided by you and by applying Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and its equality condition, I am able to solve the question. My computation gives me that $u$ is the unit vector along $grad(f)$ i.e. $u = grad(f) / || grad(f)|| $.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: I have been informed that I didn't pay sufficient attention to the statement of the question. There is a typo in Apostol's question. There is a unique unit vector so that $f'(c;u)$ (or $Df(c;u)$) equals the norm of the gradient. With absolute values there, there are of course two unit vectors possible.